# Caching result of QList::count()

Tags: c++, qt

I've been browsing some Qt code (beginner level) and I came across this bit:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> items{ collidingItems(mPlayer) };
for (int i{ 0 }, total{ items.count() }; i < total; ++i)
    if (condition())
        soSomething();
```

I've never seen the result of count() (or size() of container) be cached and I've always assumed that the compiler optimizes it. Does it? Also if it doesn't, is caching the value worth it, because I've never seen it done before in for loops, even for huge container sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `condition()` and `doSomething()` functions are in a different translation unit, the compiler can not inline them, and does not know their side-effects. One of the possible side effects of the functions is that they add or remove elements from the `items` list. Therefore the compiler can't cache `items.count()`, as it might change during the loop. In that case, caching the size into a local variable manually can make the code faster.

See https://godbolt.org/g/3co2Cb for an example (with `std::vector` instead of `QList` as the godbolt doesn't have Qt libraries, though it should be very similar). In that example one can see that with `-O2` optimizations, the manual caching into a local variable indeed produces faster code.

Note that this answer can't be generalized, it all depends on the situation, on how aggressively the compiler optimizes and inlines, whether link-time optimization is enabled etc.

Is it worth it? That also depends on your situation. If `condition()` and `doSomething()` do significant work, then the call to `items.size()` is likely irrelevant for the overall speed of the loop. If `doSomething()` and `condition()` are very small and quick, then the `items.size()` overhead might matter - but even then, this only matters if the for loop is a hotspot in your application that you need to optimize.

Comment: Good answer, but it might be worth noting that std::for_each does not suffer from this issue, as the "end" is passed as parameter to a inline function. It may be simpler to us a standard algorithm.